# ng-repeat within ng-repeat in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a record that is returned from an angular $resource promise like below.

[image]

The record is an array and within each array of record there another variable array. I try displaying in my view like below.

```
 div(ng-repeat="category in categories")
                h6
                    img(src="{{category.ImageUrl}}")
                    |{{category.Name}}
                ul(class="list-unstyled")
                    li(item in category.CategoryItems)
                        a(href="#") {{item.Item}} (0)
```

The problem is , category.CategoryItems returned undefined and empty as a result even though its actually an array of objects. Please how do i print those? Each category has category items of an array type. How do i best achieve this pls?

Comment: your `li` isn't an angular repeat, it is a jade repeat, which won't work because the data isn't being parsed by jade.  you should do it the same way you have done the `div`, i.e. `li(ng-repeat="item in category.CategoryItems")`

Comment: Sorry went throught over and over again , just can't believe i missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use ng-repeat the second time. Try this:

```
div(ng-repeat="category in categories")
            h6
                img(src="{{category.ImageUrl}}")
                |{{category.Name}}
            ul(class="list-unstyled")
                li(ng-repeat="item in category.CategoryItems")  //ng-repeat added
                    a(href="#") {{item.Item}} (0)
```

Comment: Went through over and over many times. Just can't believe i missed that.

Answer (score 0):

I used nested `ng-repeat` in my project some time ago. In my project the requirement was to show all blogs like in snapshot:

[image]

To achieve this you can use `ng-repeat` like in below code:

```
<div class="panel ">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-sm-12 "  ng-repeat="blogBlock in blogs" >
                    <h2 class="hot-topics-heading">{{blogBlock.year}}</h2>
                    <div class="blog-year>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="months in blogBlock.data">
                            <span class="hot-topics-heading">{{months.monthName}}</span>
                            <div   class="blog-month" >
                                <ul class="hot-topics-ul" >
                                      <li class="blogTitle" ng-repeat="blog in months.data">
                                         <a href="/blog/{{blog.id}}/{{blog.title | decodeURL}}">{{blog.title}}</a>
                                      </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
 </div>
```

In the above code `ng-repeat` inside the `ng-repeat` and also inside the `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="blogBlock in blogs" >
     <div ng-repeat="months in blogBlock.data">
            <ul>
                 <li ng-repeat="blog in months.data"></li>
            </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```